# pandas multiindex columns rename

Tags: python, pandas, rename, multi-index

hi I would like to rename the columns of my df. it has a multiindex columns and I would like to change the second level of it ie I have  :

|  | ('GDP US Chained 2012 Dollars SAAR', 'GDP CHWG Index') | ('GDP US Personal Consumption Chained 2012 Dollars SAAR', 'GDPCTOT Index') | ('US Gross Private Domestic Investment Total Chained 2012 SAAR', 'GPDITOTC Index') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1969-12-31 00:00:00 | 4947.1 | 3052.12 | 593.659 |
| 1970-03-31 00:00:00 | 4939.76 | 3071.06 | 575.953 |
| 1970-06-30 00:00:00 | 4946.77 | 3084.97 | 577.205 |
| 1970-09-30 00:00:00 | 4992.36 | 3112.01 | 586.598 |
| 1970-12-31 00:00:00 | 4938.86 | 3103.57 | 555.454 |

I would like to change the second row column and replace The "index" with "" and delete the ' '.
I tried :

```
df.columns.get_level_values(1).str.lower().str.replace('index', '', regex=True).str.strip()
```

it works but I can not put it in the column name

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` with lambda function and parameter `level=1`:

```
L = [('GDP US Chained 2012 Dollars SAAR', 'GDP CHWG Index'),
    ('GDP US Personal Consumption Chained 2012 Dollars SAAR', 'GDPCTOT Index'),
    ('US Gross Private Domestic Investment Total Chained 2012 SAAR', 'GPDITOTC Index')]

c = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c, index=[0])

df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lower().replace('index','').strip(), level=1)
print (df)
  GDP US Chained 2012 Dollars SAAR  \
                          gdp chwg   
0                              NaN   

  GDP US Personal Consumption Chained 2012 Dollars SAAR  \
                                                gdpctot   
0                                                NaN      

  US Gross Private Domestic Investment Total Chained 2012 SAAR  
                                                      gpditotc  
0                                                NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([ (col0, col1.lower().replace('index', ''), *more_cols) for col0, col1, *more_cols in df.columns], names=df.columns.names)
```

shoud do